# 400 BadRequest Error And Custom Error Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, http-error, bad-request

I try to have a custom error page for http error 404 page, 
then I add the following in web.config. and it can work.

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
        <clear />
        <error statusCode="401" path="~/Error/Unauthorized" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <error statusCode="403" path="~/Error/Forbidden" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="~/Error/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <error statusCode="500" path="~/Error/ServerError" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Originally, I request through web api and it will return error messages.
After adding httpErrors  in web.config. It returns only "BadRequest".

Any idea of where to look to solve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have </system.webServer></configuration> at the end of the web.config file and <configuration> at the beginning of the web.config file?

Comment: sure, i will edit the content.

Comment: Have you tried adding the <configuration></configuration> elements?  See my post below.

Comment: sure, that I post is just the part of my web.config

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
            <clear />
            <error statusCode="401" path="~/Error/Unauthorized" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="403" path="~/Error/Forbidden" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="404" path="~/Error/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="500" path="~/Error/ServerError" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```